# safe browsing with ruby

Tags: ruby

any usable ruby code to interact with the [safe browsing API](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/) from google?

i did search at google but i didn't find any mature and solid code.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 points:

(0) I'd say that [This looks alright](https://github.com/koke/malware_api), as does [this](https://github.com/juliensobrier/google-safe-browsing-lookup-ruby)

(1) Having used quite a few ruby gems for various obscure things, I find bugs all the time. It helps the open source community and the world if you find a gem, fix a bug, and let the rest of the world benefit by submitting a pull request. Tests make the life of a contributor sooooooooooo much easier, and guarantee that your fix works, so use gems with extensive tests where possible, even if they are not mature and you half-expect them to fail.

(2) From experience, gems which have lots of objects encapsulating something can sometimes be counterproductive. This has tripped me up in the case of the ruby mail gem and the tire gem (though that's not to say that they are not good and incredibly useful gems.). This applies to you if you only need to make one type of API call, say, and take a simple action. Using the simplest gem is sometimes advantageous, and for this purpose you might not need to use any gem at all! Just write a class that uses Net::HTTP to call the HTTP API: https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/lookup_guide